# Variance of polynomial and variance of sum of dependent variables

Tags: statistics

How do we compute analytically the variance of a polynomial:

$$f = a\,x^2 + b\,x$$

or also

$$f = a\,x + b\,y + c\,x\,y$$

where we can assume or not that $x$ and $y$ are independent and uncorrelated.

Comment: "Can assume or not"?!  ______ Does that mean ... both?

Comment: For the first one, $\sigma^2(f) = E(f^2)-E(f)^2$ should work beautifully. That's a reasonable plan for the second as well, but you have to be able to evaluate $E(x^iy^j)$ for small values of $i$ and $j$.

Comment: let's assume x and y are independent, unless it is a nightmare. I'm looking for the complete analytical expression. Not a simple equality... because applying basic stat shows that there are variances (and covriance) of sums hidden in the development.